# Why can't I hear when I am getting shot in the back?

Tags: pc, halo-infinite

In multiplayer, whenever I am getting shot from behind, I can barely hear the impacts of the bullets. There are the usual red indicators on the HUD that denote I'm getting shot in the back, but I find that not being able to hear the shots often throws me off and I end up dying a lot without even putting up a fight.

I thought perhaps it was an audio setting, in particular something with surround sound, but I couldn't find any settings related to that. There is a setting for adjusting the volume of bullet impacts, which I have maxed out, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

This seems uncharacteristic of other Halo games - I'm fairly certain getting shot in the back was definitely louder in previous games. Am I missing a setting or is this how the game is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apparently known audio issues with the game, as documented on [Halo Waypoint](https://support.halowaypoint.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410860512788-Audio-troubleshooting-for-Halo-Infinite):

> - Audio coming from behind or from the side is very quiet
> - Audio feels like it comes from the wrong channels

I also found this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/pvba4r/headphone_audio_bug_cant_hear_sounds_behind_me/) that is for the same problem (and for the same exact model headphones I have).  It has a potential workaround that didn't seem to work for me, but I will relist it here:

> 1. Open Device Manager.
> 2. Expand Sound, video and game controllers (not Audio inputs and outputs)
> 3. Right click your output device and click Update driver
> 4. Click Browse my computer for drivers
> 5. Click Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer
> 6. Select USB Audio Device and click Next. This will install the generic audio device drivers for this device instead.
> 7. Restart your computer (potentially optional, I had mixed results -- definitely best practice though)
> 8. Return to your Sound control panel by right-clicking the sound icon on your taskbar, clicking sound, and navigating to the Playback tab
> 9. Select your output device, and click Configure
> 10. You should now see a Stereo option. Select that, and click through Next to finish the configuration process.